# Inground trashcan missing neck

Tags: concrete, construction, underground, trash-can

I have two in ground trash cans that are missing the neck where the hinge attaches to the lid. When it rains, water gets in and fills the hole. I have a 32 gallon plastic trash can that I put in and when it rains hard it starts floating with the lid on top.

Is there a way I can fix this myself?
[image: in ground trascans]

[image: in ground traahcans]

Comment: What’s the bottom of the hole like? Where is water supposed to drain?  Any hole in the ground that supposed to stay dry must have a drainage method.  One possible theory: the bottom might have once been gravel, which over the years silted up and now doesn’t allow drainage fast enough.

Comment: The walls are concrete and has a green lining. There doesn't seem to be a drainage. I've seen others around where the the rim (neck) extends from the floor and the spring loaded hinge connects the lid. I'm assuming this prevents water to come in. Right now it is on an incline and since it doesn't extend over the floor water flows in the holes.

Comment: So when it rains and fills up with water, how do you get the water out?

Comment: Usually it doesn't really fill up to the top unless it really rains a lot. Sometimes I have to get a bucket and remove the excess water. Some evaporates. Some seeps out somehow.

Comment: i would put  brick under the can so that it breaks the plane slightly and you can lid it without a coupling